# Usage guidelines for JDBC with Spring

Tags: spring-data, spring-jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

So recently there´s a new player in the Spring JDBC eco system:
JdbcClient
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/JdbcClient.html

We also (still) got this:
JdbcTemplate
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Beside that we already got:
Spring Data Jdbc
https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc

And today i saw this:
JdbcOperations
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-modulith/blob/main/spring-modulith-events/spring-modulith-events-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/modulith/events/jdbc/JdbcEventPublicationRepository.java#L32

While i usually go with Spring Data Jdbc (which is absolutely great by the way) i wonder why there is so much Jdbc (let`s say) stuff around?

As far as i can see there is everything you need (JDBC related) already shipped in Spring Data JDBC.

So i´m curious to know what kind of problems are you expected to solve with the new `JdbcClient`?
Futhermore: why is this even there?

I mean the whole Spring Data JDBC library isn't that much space wasted (as one might argument), isn`t it?

And why is there a `JdbcOperations`?

I`m kind of confused on where the (jdbc) journey is going in the spring ecosystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading through https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/jdbc/core.html for more details.

But here is an overview starting from the lowest level of abstraction.

### JdbcTemplate

[`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) is actually an implementation of [`JdbcOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html)
Everything is build on those. Make JDBC just a little bit easier to use, by:

- abstracting away Exception handling. Ever tried to properly handle exceptions for JDBC method calls, that need clean up which in turn might throw the same kind of exception? Don't use a `JdbcTemplate` instead.
- delegating the extraction of data from a `ResultSet` into `ResultSetExtractor`, `RowMapper` and `ResultSetExtractor`
- simplifying many typical use cases, like executing a query and getting the result as a `List<Object>`

But you still provide the SQL you want to execute and the `JdbcTemplate` does very little with that SQL. (It actually does some replacements for collection like parameters)

### NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

[`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) implements [`NamedParameterJdbcOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcOperations.html) and is build on top of `JdbcOperations`.

It allows you to use named parameters, i.e. things like `:myval` in your SQL statements instead of the standard JDBC `?` placeholder.

All the classes mentioned so far are really old. They exist since Spring 2.0 or before. `JdbcTemplate` has a `@since May 3, 2001`!

### JdbcClient

[`JdbcClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/JdbcClient.html) offers a fluent interface and is a fairly new addition.
It offers most of the capabilities of `NamedParameterJdbcOperations` and `JdbcOperations` with a fluent interface.

In order to do that it actually uses `NamedParameterJdbcOperations` and `JdbcOperations` under the hood.

### Spring Data JDBC

[Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc) is an ORM based on the ideas of Domain Driven Design. This means you create entity classes and Spring Data JDBC will create and execute SQL for you to persist, find and load such entities. You use Repositories for interacting with the database which you declare as interfaces and Spring Data will provide implementations. For simple use cases you won't have to write any SQL at all.

Agains Spring Data JDBC is build on the classes mentioned above, especially `NamedParameterJdbcOperations`

### What should I use?

1. If you just want to execute some SQL use a `JdbcClient`.
   It is nice to use and in most cases will be up to the job.
2. If you need one of the features not supported by `JdbcClient`, or if you don't like a fluent interface fall back on `JdbcOperations` or `NamedParameterJdbcOperations` or some other class. The reference documentation has this not about the topic:

   > `JdbcClient` is a flexible but simplified facade for JDBC query/update statements. Advanced capabilities such as batch inserts and stored procedure calls typically require extra customization: consider Spring’s `SimpleJdbcInsert` and `SimpleJdbcCall` classes or plain direct `JdbcTemplate` usage for any such capabilities not available in JdbcClient.
3. If you need an ORM, because you have a rich object model that needs to be persisted to a database use Spring Data JDBC
4. Mix all the options from above. Since everything eventually uses a `JdbcTemplate` you can have instances of all these classes in your program and use the matching one for each individual use case.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot. Just being curious ... Speaking about your 4. argument - If i use Spring Data JDBC do i have access to this underlying classes like NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or JdbcClient/JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Yes, you can autowire them.